# How to reload specific TableViewController's tableview in a singleton class in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, delegates, singleton

I have a AAATableViewController with tableView.

And I have a separate swift singleton file.

In a singleton, I have a function with some logic and in this logic,

I have

```
   DispatchQueue.main.async {              
      self.tableView.reloadData()
   }
```

but it shows an error because there is no tableview in a singleton class.

How can I reload AAATableViewController's tableview inside singleton using delegate and protocol?

I read some articles with delegate , but they are all between viewcontrollers, and couldn't figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am making some assumptions about the structure of your code, but I think you're going to want something like this:

```
protocol ReloadDelegate: AnyObject {
    func reloadTable()
}

struct Singleton {
    weak var reloadDelegate: ReloadDelegate?
    static var shared = Singleton()

    func doSomething() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.reloadDelegate?.reloadTable()
        }
    }
}

class TableViewController: UITableViewController, ReloadDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        Singleton.shared.reloadDelegate = self
    }

    func reloadTable() {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

When you create the TableViewController, you'll need to set the Singleton's reload delegate to the TableViewController. Now the Singleton knows about the TableViewController and can tell it to reload.

Comment: Thank you. This works fine , and it helped me to understand delegeate.Can I ask why I should use weak in var reloadDelegate? What  happens if I use without weark keyword?

Comment: hello @alphonse. Sorry for the late response.  Technically it will still work fine without weak, but there will be a memory leak. Using weak here avoids a retain cycle between the delegate and Singleton and the TableViewController. (you read up on it here https://medium.com/mackmobile/avoiding-retain-cycles-in-swift-7b08d50fe3ef).